# Ants infestation on bicycle

Tags: maintenance, cleaning

During the recent trip my road bicycle was mounted on the rack on top of the car, and since I didn't wrap it, nor used the cover, flies and other small insects got stuck on the frame and handlebars. After the trip I gave my bike a thorough wash to clean the remains of the insects, but soon I noticed bunch of ants crawling over the bicycle.

While I can safely use repellents or poisons to get rid of the ants from my home, I'm interested if there are any considerations I have to take when treating the bike with such products, in order not to damage the components or paint (FTR, my bike has alloy frame and carbon fork, Shimano 105 group).

Comment: There is no reason for ants to infest your bike, assuming you do not have any foodstuffs on the bike or somehow stuffed down one of the tubes.  I suspect that the ants crawled onto the bike after you washed it.

Comment: I wonder if the remains of other insects count as food? I'd re-wash and if the problem persists, see your {mechanic}

Comment: They probably just found some food ( ant food ) on your bike, I'd let them clean it off.

Comment: Do you use energy drinks? If some dripped from your bottle onto the frame that would explain it as Ants love the stuff

Comment: Use soapy water or water with some vinegar added and rinse thoroughly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ants don't really have any reason to stay in/on your bike. Worst case, depending on how bad it is, I would wash it down using soapwater. That way if there is any sweet juice or bug parts left to eat and make your bike more attractive to ants, it would no longer be a problem. Good Luck, I hope you can reclaim your bike back from the ants! Next time the ants should buy their own bike... not satisfied with an anthill I guess :-)